# Exercicio Algoritmo Dados os valores de x real e n natural positivo, calcular

Tags: algoritmo, pseudocódigo

Dados os valores de `x` real e `n` natural positivo, calcular:

```
S = (x+1)/1! + (x+2)/2! + (x+3)/3! + ... + (x+n)/n!
```

Até agora o que eu fiz foi isso:

```
leia x
leia n
nFatorial = 1    
contadorFatorial = 0
enquanto contadorFatorial < n faça             */Aqui é uma funçao pra calcular fatorial
  |contadorFatorial = contadorFatorial + 1
  |nFatorial = nFatorial * contadorFatorial
fim enquanto
s1 = x+1
sn = x+n/nFatorial
nFatorial2 = 1
contadorFatorial2 = 0
enquanto sn < s1 faça              
  |n = n - 1
  |enquanto contadorFatorial2 < n faça            */Calcular Fatorial
    |contadorFatorial2 = contadorFatorial2 + 1
    |nFatorial2 = nFatorial2 * contadorFatorial2
```

Mas não consigo sair disso.

edit

Acho que consegui resolver, mas provavelmente tem algum jeito que gaste bem menos linhas. Ficou assim:

```
leia x    
leia n
nFatorial = 1
contadorFatorial = 0
enquanto contadorFatorial < n faça
  |contadorFatorial = contadorFatorial + 1
  |nFatorial = nFatorial * contadorFatorial
fim enquanto
s1 = x+1
sn = (x+n)/nFatorial
soma = sn
enquanto sn < s1 faça
  |n = n - 1
  |nFatorial2 = 1
  |contadorFatorial2 = 0
  |enquanto contadorFatorial2 < n faça
    |contadorFatorial2 = contadorFatorial2 + 1
    |nFatorial2 = nFatorial2 * contadorFatorial2
  fim enquanto
  |sn2 = (x+n)/nFatorial2
  |soma = soma + sn2
  |sn = sn2
fim enquanto
escreva "o valor de S é", soma
fim
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se observar a fórmula:

```
S = (x+1)/1! + (x+2)/2! + (x+3)/3! + ... + (x+n)/n!
```

Nota-se que só é necessário 1 repetição que itera todos os valores de 1 a `n`.
Exatamente como você fez na primeira repetição.

```
contadorFatorial = 0
enquanto contadorFatorial < n faça
    contadorFatorial = contadorFatorial + 1
```

Logo, você não precisaria de uma segunda repetição, é aí que talvez você esteja se confundindo.

Pense o seguinte, se você tem uma fórmula que usa valores de 1 a `n`, quantos blocos de repetição você precisa? Nesse caso, 1 só.
Tente fazer o cálculo no mesmo bloco de repetição (ou seja, utilizando apenas 1 "enquanto").

Dica:
Lembre que X! = X * (X - 1)!

Logo, se eu tenho 4!, para calcular 5! eu só preciso fazer 4! * 5, visto que: 5! = 5 * (5-1)!

O cálculo é bem mais simples do que você imagina. Quanto mais repetições você usa, mais complexidade você coloca no seu código.

Outra DICA:
Você está usando 3 "enquanto" no seu código, sendo que só é necessário 1, tente fazer com apenas 1 e, para cada iteração, você calcula cada uma das parcelas da soma.